# Every other word

Tags: phrase-usage

Let's say you talk with someone on the internet and you don't hear every word the one says, like one word after another, because of the bad internet connection, then, is it correct to say so?

> We hear you ***every other word*** because of intermittent connection

Comment: We usually say "Your voice is cracking in between", or "Your voice is going dead alternatively/alternately", or "We are able to hear only alternate words".

Comment: "We can only hear about every other word."

Comment: @Kate Bunting can't "you" go after "can" in your example?

Comment: No, the sense is ..."about every other word that you say". _You every other word_ is not idiomatic English.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say, "We have a bad connection. We can only hear every other word you say."

In real life it's unlikely that you would really hear the first word, not the second, hear the 3rd, not the 4th, etc, in such a regular pattern. I might still say "we can only hear every other word" as an approximation of the real problem. No one's going to keep track carefully enough to say, "I heard the first, third, seventh, ninth, and twelfth words you said but not the second, fourth, fifth ..." etc. But we're more likely to say, "I'm sorry, this is a bad connection, you keep breaking up" or something more general like that.